# Assign values to multiple symbolic variables at the same time

Tags: matlab

I wanna assign values to multiple symbolic variables at the same time.

For example,

```
syms a b c
% for several reasons, I have to define a, b, c as symbolic variables.

x = [a, b, c];
y = [1, 2, 3];
```

When I define matrix x and y like above,
I wanna get following answer.

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
% Assign values to symbolic variables.
```

Of course, simply I can get this answer by using following code.

```
[a, b, c] = deal(1, 2, 3);
```

But I have to use matrix x and y instead of [a, b, c] and (1, 2, 3).
Because actually there are so many symbolic variables in matrix x when I calculate. 
So I wanna use matrix.

In this case, if I use matrix x and y

```
x = deal(y);
```

The answer is just

```
x = 1 2 3
```

But I wanna get the answer,

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

What should I do to assign values to variables by using matrix x and y?
Please answer my question.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. `syms a; a=1` overwrites the symbolic variable and creates a double with value 1. Thus all answers to your previous question apply here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be trying to do this, I am sure there must be some other choices you could make earlier to avoid this problem. But it can be done, probably more nicely than I have done.

```
syms a b c
x=[a b c]
y=[1 2 3]

%// We want to get the name of the variable from x, and the value from y
arrayfun(@(i) assignin('caller',char(x(i)),y(i)),1:length(x))
```